# VB select from drop down menu in web browser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I created a simple form with 4 `TextBox` and 1 `Button`.

I'm trying to fill a form in a web page.

I successfully filled all the 'normal' text boxes, but I also have a drop down menu for date and month which I don't know how to make it select from the drop down menu.

For normal text, I did this and it worked:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InnerText = tz.Text$
```

and then I tried the same for the drop down menu, didn't work:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").InnerHtml = month.Text$

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("year").InnerHtml = year.Text$
```

I have 2 `ComboBox` with the names 'month' and 'year'.

I checked the element `ID` by inspecting the drop down menu from the web page, but when ever I select month and year from my combo box and send it, it will fill the date form with nothing (NULL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your job in a button clieck event and first wait for the webpage loads completely.Some of controls comes with the main html codes some of them is being created after page load so after you navigate your browser you should wait until it completes the page load completely.

```
browser.Navigate("https://www.website.com/")
 While browser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
 End While
'use the webpage now
```

Now you gotta find the selectboxes and select an option in it.

```
 For Each elm As Object In browser.Document.all
            If elm.Id = "idOfTheWebControl" Then
                elm.SetAttribute("value", your_value)
            End If
 Next
```